# did not found the tool menu in macOS with vlc

Tags: macos, vlc

When I open the vlc(`Version 3.0.20 Vetinari (Apple Silicon)`) in macOS 13.3.1, I did not found the tools menu, does the vlc did not contains tools menu in macOS?

[image]

how to found the tools menu? should I enable it by myself? I have tried to enable it like this:

[image]

still could not found the menu.

Comment: Based on what do you assume there should be a Tools menu?

Comment: It's never had one on Mac. What are you looking for? On Mac, Prefs are always Cmd/comma, or under the [application name] menu. With VLC, there are two 'sets' of prefs, simple & advanced. Use the 'Show All' button to see the advanced.